# vector space of positive functions

Tags: statistics, differential-geometry

I am reading Murray and Rice's "Differential Geometry and Statistics," and here is something I don't understand.

> In general it is clear that the multiplication of positive densities by positive functions gives a family of transformations of the set of positive densities parametrised by positive functions. However, positive functions don't form a vector space. We can rectify this situation by considering an arbitrary function $f$ to act on densities through multiplication by $e^{f}$. (9)

This is really important for what follows, so I need to understand it. A positive density is a probability density that doesn't need to add up to 1, for example a normal distribution with $\mu$ and $\sigma$ as parameters. It is not clear to me what M&R mean when they say that the "positive densities are parametrised by positive functions." More importantly, it is not clear to me in what way positive functions are not vector spaces that can be fixed by multiplying by $e^{f}$ instead of $f$ itself.

Comment: Well, positive functions are not a real/complex vector space because if $f$ is positive, $(-1) \cdot f$ won't be. Also, $f = 0$ is not positive.

Comment: So, the space of functions $e^{f}$ with $f$ a positive function is a vector space because for any real number $a$, $e^{af}$ is a function $e^{g}$ where $g$ is a positive function. Thank  you!

Comment: To be honest, I don't know any diff. geometry yet, so I don't have much intuition on this question. I figured I could answer the part I did know how to. You'd have to define that product fromally to see if it behaves well, I'm not entirely confident that it'll work.

Comment: Thank you. It looks like M&R want to show how $p_{1}$ can be translated to $p_{2}$ using a function $f$. We could just use $f(x)=x\cdot{}\frac{p_{2}}{p_{1}}$, which is a positive function, but as Guido says, positive functions are not a vector space. Instead, use $f(x)=\log\frac{p_{2}}{p_{1}}$ and the translation "$p_{1}$ is translated to $p_{2}$ by $f$ if and only if $p_{1}=e^{f}p_{2}$". Now the space of positive measures together with the space of measurable functions form an affine space, for which we needed a vector space, and the positive functions alone cannot provide it. Thanks, Guido.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $g$ is a positive function, then $f := \log g$ is a function and $g = e^{f}$. With obvious notation, the space of positive functions becomes a vector space under the operations:

- Addition: $g_{1} \oplus g_{2} = g_{1} g_{2} = e^{f_{1} + f_{2}}$;
- Scalar multiplication: $c \odot g = g^{c} = e^{cf}$.

A "positive density" is presumably a *positive differential form of top degree*. If $\mu_{0}$ is any fixed positive density, then an arbitrary positive density $\mu$ has the form $e^{f}\, \mu_{0}$, with $f = \log(\mu/\mu_{0})$. (A ratio of positive densities is a positive function.)